# Selecting a specific menu item from a context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I am working on a C# WPF application. I have a context menu appear on a textbook using Infragistics library. I want to be able to use my keyboard to scroll through the options and select one of them (by pressing enter key). I can see items being selected on the menu when I scroll through them but I don't know how to get the text in the menu item (like "cp", "high" etc.) when the user hits enter. Doing something like xamMenu.Items.CurrentItem is always returning null.

Comment: So you are using the XamContextMenu on the TextBox?  The XamMenuItem should have a Click event that you can handle and the sender will be the XamMenuItem that was clicked.  This event will fire even when you press Enter to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code behind, or are the list items bound to a property in your viewmodel?

If the latter: create an additional property SelectedItem of the same type that your list items are, and in the viewmodel :

```
<ComboBox 
 ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModel.Items}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding MyViewModel.SelectedItem}"
 ToolTip="some tooltip" 
/>
```

Then SelectedItem should take the right value.

Comment: The whole menu gets constructed in code-behind. I am trying to modify do what I want to do in the KeyDown event handler: _xamMenu.KeyDown += (s, e) => { // Populate a textbox with the menu option which is currently highlighted}. But I do not know how to access the content of highlighted option.